# ASP.NET - accessing database table in authentication attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building ASP.NET Web API 2 (MVC 6) application using this tutorial: http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/

Everything went fine, but now I want to access the `ApplicationsUsers` table in `HMACAuthenticationAttribute`. How can I do that? Is making the `allowedApps` dictionary public static, and adding every freshly registered user to this dictionary the only possible solution? How can I access dbcontext here?

For people who do not want to read that tutorial: I need to access dbcontext in `IAuthenticationFilter`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable of your `DbContext` on the `HMACAuthenticationAttribute` class.
I would not recommend to let the `allowedApps` as a static variable if your app is going to create a lot of app Ids. It could be public variable. But i would recommend to make addition to the dictionary available through a separate method, with that you could gain more control over what is being inserted into the `allowedApps`